# Squishit.Less doesn't do anything

Tags: less, squishit

I've used package manager to install Squishit.Less 0.9.3, and I have two files

1. style.less - `@import "test.less";`
2. test.less - `body{background-color: pink;}`.

In my page I have:

```
<%= Bundle.Css().Add("~/less/style.less").ForceRelease().Render("~/less/combined.css") %>
```

But the output I get is: `@import"test.less";` - the less processor hasn't tried to get the import for some reason?

I've tried `ProcessImports` but that made no difference.

Comment: you will have to set your import path maybe? Or use @import "~/less/test.less";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just verified in a sample project that it works correctly.

You should NOT need to call ProcessImports - the less preprocessor should do this automatically.  ProcessImports is for @imports in standard CSS, which aren't processed by default.

I suspect what happened is that NuGet didn't add the file that registers the preprocessor.  As a result the less preprocessor is never called.  If you look under App_Start you should see a file called SquishItLess.cs with the following contents:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.App_Start.SquishItLess), "Start")]

namespace MyProject.App_Start
{
    using SquishIt.Framework;
    using SquishIt.Less;

    public class SquishItLess
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Bundle.RegisterStylePreprocessor(new LessPreprocessor());
        }
    }
}
```

If this file is missing, you can either add it or add the Bundle.RegisterStylePreprocessor line in your Global.asax.cs' Application_Start method.

If you're installing to a VB project this is a known issue (https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/issues/232) and will be addressed when the plug is pulled on .net 3.5 support.

Comment: This could be it as I think it worked on another machine, and the visual studio versions are different (back in 2010 on the one that's not working)... I'll check now, thanks!

Comment: OK - you were right - but there was another problem when I stopped using the test.less, and started including my .css file - this was left as a CSS include and using .ProcessIncludes() made no difference - I changed the extension to .css.less and it worked. I can start a new question for that issue?

Comment: A new question probably makes sense.  I think we have a way to get this working, will hopefully get a chance to research by the time you've posted it.