# SquishIt.Less ProcessIncludes() not working for CSS file

Tags: css, less, squishit

I have a Less file which includes a CSS file, then a set of Less files. With SquishIt I want to combine and minify these, but it ignores the CSS file unless I rename it to .css.less. I believe ProcessIncludes() is intended for this purpose but makes no difference.

Does anyone know why ProcessIncludes() doesn't do anything on a CSS file linked in a Less file?

(This is a follow up to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197604) about Squishit.Less not working at all, it now works for the Less files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration option for dotLess called "InlineCssFiles" that I believe does what you need.  You can use your own configuration by overriding the static property "EngineBuilder" (its a Func) on less preprocessor.  So in App_Start you could do something like this:

```
LessPreprocessor.EngineBuilder = () => new EngineFactory
            {
                Configuration = new DotlessConfiguration
                    {
                        InlineCssFiles = true,
                    }
            }.GetEngine();
```

Comment: I have an issue on my test server that means I can't test this at the moment - but that sounds like the option I needed instead of ProcessIncludes. I can't find any decent docs for SquishIt.Less - I guess I needed to open the source! :\

Comment: Yeah that's always a problem.  I think I'm going to spend a little time adding /// comments to the important public methods and see what is out there to generate docs from that.  I don't really use .less but I read a bit yesterday and I think that the option above will help you.

Comment: Not sure when I can go back to test this. Have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to LESS documentation:

> You can import both CSS and LESS files. Only LESS files import statements are processed, CSS file import statements are kept as they are.

You can force LESS to process a CSS file by:

```
@import (less) "file.css";
```

Note however that all this applies to the [official LESS implementation](http://lesscss.org) and may not work in SquishIt. SquishIt seems to use the [dotless](http://dotlesscss.org) compiler which is pretty much outdated.